# Move files created based on today's date - powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script that does the following:

Move the latest 3 subfolders(a-b-c with files) into a new folder with today's date without moving older files

Security has  3 subfolders generated today along with subfolders from previous days.

```
$localpath ="D:\Security\"

Get-ChildItem $localpath -Recurse | foreach {
$DateofFile = $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()
$Todaysfolder = Get-Date $DateofFile -Format yyyMMdd
$targetpath =  $Todaysfolder

Create directory if it doesn't exsist
if (!(Test-Path $targetpath))
{
 New-Item $targetpath  -type directory
}

 Get-ChildItem  $localpath | Move-Item -Destination $targetpath

}
```

Process right now is grabbing all files - even the ones that were not created today and grouping them into one folder. This script will run at the end of the day to move those 3 subfolders (A-B-C) into today's folder "20200520" example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to recurse Get-ChildItem when moving the entire folder - saves you looping through contained files.

```
$FromPath ="C:\fromtest"
$ToPath = "C:\totest\"+(Get-Date -Format yyyMMdd)

$FoldersToMove = Get-ChildItem $FromPath | 
    Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).date}

#Create directory if it doesn't exsist
if (!(Test-Path $ToPath)){
    New-Item $ToPath -type directory
}

foreach ($Folder in $FoldersToMove){
    $Folder | Move-Item -Destination $ToPath
}
```